# Why \b does not match word using .net regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

To review regular expresions I read [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial). Anyways that tutorial mentions that `\b` matches a word boundary (between \w and \W characters). That tutorial also gives a link where you can install expresso (program that helps when creating regular expressions).

So I have created my regular expressions in expresso and I do inded get a match. Now when I copy the same regex to visual studio I do not get a match. Take a look:

---

[image]

---

[image]

Why am I not getting a match? in the immediate window I am showing the content of variable output. In expresso I do get a match and in visual studio I don't. why?

Comment: Do you have to double escape the `\b`?

Comment: is `output` the given words shown in the picture?

Comment: I can't view the images perhaps due to a firewall at work, but just to make sure, do you need to escape the backslash, i.e. write ``\\b``?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The **C# language** and **.NET Regular Expressions** both have their own distinct set of backslash-escape sequences, but the C# compiler is intercepting the `"\b"` in your string and converting it into an ASCII backspace character so the `RegEx` class never sees it. You need to make your string verbatim (prefix with an at-symbol) or double-escape the 'b' so the backslash is passed to RegEx like so:

```
@"\bCOMPILATION UNIT";
```

Or

```
"\\bCOMPILATION UNIT"
```

I'll say the .NET RegEx documentation does not make this clear. It took me a while to figure this out at first too.

Fun-fact: The `\r` and `\n` characters (carriage-return and line-break respectively) and some others are recognized by *both* RegEx and the C# language, so the end-result is the same, even if the compiled string is different.

Comment: or, as commented, double-backslashes: `"\\bCOMPILATION UNIT"` (+1)

Comment: Wow that was giving me a hard time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `@"\bCOMPILATION UNIT"`.  This is a verbatim literal.  When you do `"\b"` instead, it parses `\b` into a special character.  You can also do `"\\b"`, whose double backslash is parsed into a real backslash, but it's generally easier to just use verbatims when dealing with regex.